# Find four adjacent empty cells in Excel

Tags: excel, array-formulas, is-empty

I have a problem with finding empty cells in table. What I want to do is to find empty parts of the table (empty part - four or more empty cells in a row).

Table:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Name | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 | Day4 | Day5 | Day6 | Day7 | Day8 | Day9 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A    |    1 |    8 |    2 |    7 |      |    8 |    4 |      |    1 |
| B    |    2 |    8 |    4 |      |      |      |      |    5 |    7 |
| C    |    2 |      |    6 |    7 |      |    8 |    9 |    7 |      |
| D    |    4 |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |    8 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

The answer with this example should be something like this:

```
B empty Day4 - Day7  
D empty Day2 - Day8
```

I guess I need to use array formula, but I do not have experience with that...

I would appreciate any help or comments.
Thanks!

Comment: Is "Empty" always a blank cell or just an empty string? also: how to deal with rows which only have something in "Day 5"?

Comment: "Empty" is always a blank cell. If there is something only in Day5 then formula has to find that all the cells before are blank and the answer should be "empty Day1-Day4"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the headers in A1:J1 and the data in B3:J3. To check for each row itself, a formula like this:

```
=IF(MIN(LEN(B3:G3&C3:H3&D3:I3&E3:J3)),"",INDEX(B$1:G$1,1,MATCH(0,LEN(B3:G3&C3:H3&D3:I3&E3:J3),0))&" - "&INDEX(B$1:J$1,1,MATCH(1,(INDEX(B3:G3,1,MATCH(0,LEN(B3:G3&C3:H3&D3:I3&E3:J3),0)):I3="")*(INDEX(B3:G3,1,MATCH(0,LEN(B3:G3&C3:H3&D3:I3&E3:J3),0)+1):J3<>""),0)+MATCH(0,LEN(B3:G3&C3:H3&D3:I3&E3:J3),0)-1))
```

would do.

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>!

After that you can simply auto fill down the formula. And it will show for each row itself (if 4+ cells in a row are empty) the headers of the first and last empty cell of that range. Also the cells do not need to be blank (empty stings also work).

To automatically collapse it to have the output exactly like you want it, you would need to array that array formula again (which is not possible for some parts and also would consume lots of resources.

[image]